# Remove the duplicate row in apache pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to remove the duplicate rows in pig. There are a lot of ways, but I am not sure if which one is better.

Here is the data set, the schema is (f0,f1,id,f3,f4):

```
1,2,3,2015-02-21,2015-02-20
1,2,3,2015-02-22,2015-02-20
1,2,3,2015-02-23,2015-02-20
1,2,4,2015-02-24,2015-02-20
1,2,5,2015-02-25,2015-02-20
```

If any of rows whose f0,f1 and id are equal, then they are considered to be the duplicate. And I want to output one of them where f3 is minimum.

But I also want to output which ids have the duplicates.

That is, I will store or dump two relations.

one of both relations are:

```
1,2,3,2015-02-21,2015-02-20
1,2,4,2015-02-24,2015-02-20
1,2,5,2015-02-25,2015-02-20
```

The other one is the id which has the duplicate rows, the schema is (id,f4)

```
3,2015-02-20
```

That is, id=3 has the duplicate data.

Here is my workaround

```
r1 = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',');
r2 =  group r1 by ($0,$1,$2);
r3 = FOREACH r2 GENERATE COUNT(r1) as c, r1;
SPLIT r3 into r4 if c > 1, r5 if c == 1;
r6 = FOREACH r5 GENERATE flatten(r1);

dups_id = FOREACH r4 {
GENERATE flatten(r1.$2),flatten(r1.$4);
};

r7= distinct dups_id

dump r7

no_dups = FOREACH r4 {
sorted = ORDER r1 by $3 ASC;
lim = limit sorted 1;
GENERATE flatten(lim);
};

r8 = union no_dups,r6

dump r8
```

I think that this is a little complicated, and I doubt the performance.

Is there any other better idea can implement this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

```
r1 = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',');
r2 = group r1 by ($0,$1,$2);
r3 = FOREACH r2 GENERATE $0.., SIZE($1) AS size;
DEFINE MYTOP TOP('ASC');
r8 = FOREACH r2 {
    GENERATE MYTOP(1, 3, r1);
};

dups = FILTER r3 BY size > 1L;
dups2 = FOREACH dups GENERATE FLATTEN($1);
dups3 = FOREACH dups2 GENERATE $2, $4;
dups_id = DISTINCT dups3;

dump r8;
dump dups_id;
```

Comment: It will output
2015-03-30 10:24:00,919 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'TOP' with arguments '[ASC]'

Comment: Looks like this feature was shipped with 0.14.0. You can replace TOP with ORDER BY ASC; and LIMIT 1.